# Unordered list not appearing on web page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a list of links just in case my hotspots don't work in my image map, but they won't appear in the page.

I've tried changing the style code, and rearranging the html code to get it to work properly but it still does not appear anywhere on the page.

```
<div>
<p class="instructions">
Click on one of the fruits to go to its corresponding <br /> web page.
</p>
<p class="descbox2">
Clicking on the left Cherry will send you to a web page about how to grow 
Cherry trees.
<br /><br />
Clicking the grapes will take you to a web page on how to grow Raisins.
<br /><br />
Clicking the triangular Watermelon piece will send you to a web page 
for<br />
different ways to cut Watermelon.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Orange will send you to a web page about how to grow Orange 
trees.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Pineapple will take you to a web page about how to grow 
Pineapples from its top.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Strawberry will take you to a web page for Froberg's Farm 
located<br />
in Alvin,TX to pick your own Strawberries.
<br /><br />
If image links aren't working click the links below to go to the web 
pages used.
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/how-to-grow/fruit- 
trees/cherry-trees" Cherry Trees </a></li>
</ul>
</p>
<img src="Images/fruitclipart.jpg" alt="Clipart of fruit" 
usemap="#fruits">
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? What should appear?

Comment: Right now there should only be one list item link that reads Cherry Trees under the line that says "If image links aren't working click the links below" but its not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on a closing tag `>` in your opening `a` tag

Before:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/how-to-grow/fruit- 
trees/cherry-trees" Cherry Trees </a></li>
</ul>
```

After:

```html
<div>
<p class="instructions">
Click on one of the fruits to go to its corresponding <br /> web page.
</p>
<p class="descbox2">
Clicking on the left Cherry will send you to a web page about how to grow 
Cherry trees.
<br /><br />
Clicking the grapes will take you to a web page on how to grow Raisins.
<br /><br />
Clicking the triangular Watermelon piece will send you to a web page 
for<br />
different ways to cut Watermelon.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Orange will send you to a web page about how to grow Orange 
trees.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Pineapple will take you to a web page about how to grow 
Pineapples from its top.
<br /><br />
Clicking the Strawberry will take you to a web page for Froberg's Farm 
located<br />
in Alvin,TX to pick your own Strawberries.
<br /><br />
If image links aren't working click the links below to go to the web 
pages used.
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/how-to-grow/fruit- 
trees/cherry-trees"> Cherry Trees </a></li>
</ul>
</p>
<img src="Images/fruitclipart.jpg" alt="Clipart of fruit" 
usemap="#fruits">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the opening `<a>` tag.

So this:

```
<a href="https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/how-to-grow/fruit-trees/cherry-trees" Cherry Trees </a>
```

Should be this:

```
<a href="https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/how-to-grow/fruit-trees/cherry-trees"> Cherry Trees </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want parts of your map to function as links, you should first define the map area

```
<img src="Images/fruitclipart.jpg" alt="Clipart of fruit" 
usemap="#fruits">    
<map name="fruits">
  <area shape="cherry" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="cherry">
  <area shape="raisins" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="raisins">
  <area shape="watermelon" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="watermelon">
</map>
```

How to find the coordinates? checkout this tool - https://www.image-map.net/